# Public Dashboard Input Widget

Tags: widget, dashboard, permission-denied, thingsboard

I have a public dashboard (shared with one user as a POC) with an input widget. The problem is every time they try to enter a value they get a "permission denied".

It's a POC for a few weeks but it's quite important as it's what they are using to judge whether or not to go ahead.

Read the THingsboard Docs on permissions

Thanks for any help!